Guardar un dataframe en un archivo json con un nombre específico sin crear archivos de partición en Pyspark/Spark/Pandas
Estoy intentando guardar un df en una ruta de storageAccount, pero se ha estado guardando con las particiones por ser propio de spark, lo que necesito es borrar lo que existe en la carpeta o sea en la ruta que se tiene, una vez eliminado lo que se tiene, entonces escribir el dataframe con los datos nuevos. Intente lo siguiente:
Con esto se guardar con varias partitiones y ademas de los archivos de _committed, de _started y de _SUCCESS
import pandas as pd import json  dbutils.fs.rm(file_output_path, True) df_data.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(file_output_path) 
Crea un solo archivo de part-0000-tid... y los archivos de _committed, de _started y de _SUCCESS
df_data.coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(file_output_path)
enter image description here
Tambien intente convertir el df a json antes de guardar, el json se crea bien como debe ser, y al intentar guardarlo
import json json_data = [json.loads(row) for row in df_data.toJSON().collect()] json_string = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4) with open(file_output_path, 'w') as f:    //Marca error de: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/mnt/.../.../.../../' f.write(json_data) print(json_string)  //Aqui le hago un print al json, y el formato del json es correcto.
